# How to initiate standby/sleep from command-line?

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, standby, sleep-mode

I have found a lot of info about how to shut down computer, put it in hibernation etc via the command line, however, any tips i have read about getting it to sleep as it does from the start-menu has so far not worked properly.

I would like a command that puts the computer in a light standby mode where a keypress would make the computer wake again, and not in hibernation. Does anyone know of this?

AFAIK, rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 does NOT put the computer to sleep / standby in all cases, and is as such not appropriate for my use...

Thanks,
Araho

Comment: In which cases does that command not put the computer to sleep?

Comment: In my case, at least :P Well, it puts it into hibernation just like shutdown -h. I want the same kind of sleep as i get when i use the start-menu -> sleep.

Comment: Did you look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu-in-windows-vista (The second answer.) You could turn off hibernation temporarily, then turn it back on upon awakening...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @minitech, I finally got it working. Leaving this here for all who want to know the answer, and giving two examples, one in direct command-line and one in Visual C#:

Add elevated priveleges to your app:

- In other words, in command-line, start it as Administrator.
- In Visual C#, which is what I'm using, add a manifest file to the project, and edit the "requestedExecutionLevel"-element to the following:

Then run the following commands:

- In commandline:

  1. "powercfg -hibernate off" - This shuts off the hibernation mode possibility.
  2. rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 - This makes the computer sleep.
  3. powercfg -hibernate on - This allows the hibernation mode to again be activated.
- In Visual C#, use the following code:

  1. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("powercfg", "-hibernate off"); // Turn off hibernation mode setting.
  2. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0"); // Send the computer to sleep
  3. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("powercfg", "-hibernate on"); // Turn on hibernation mode setting after waking computer.

It is **very** important to remember to add Administrator priveleges, or it will make the computer hibernate, which takes forever.

Araho

Answer (score 1):

**STANDBY** (SLEEP) with CMD (command prompt or .bat), doesnt work in Windows 10.

Use  [**QUICK SLEEPER**](http://j.mp/sleeptt).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^!Numpad9::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
^!Numpad8::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 1, "int", 0, "int", 0)
```

in [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You'd then have to press Ctrl+Alt+Numpad9. Ctrl+Alt+Numpad8 is for putting it into hibernation mode.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested NirCMd (useful for many things) has both a Standby (sleep) and Hibernate command:
https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/standby.html
Likely does some of the above for you.